# Can I take Kinder Happy Hippos though TSA (USA)?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink

I know America has a ban on some Kinder products, my girlfriend loves Kinder Happy Hippos, and because of this I told her I would bring her 5 full boxes of them with me. (She lives in America, and they are hard to find)

Will there be an issue with me taking this amount with me to America from England?

Comment: TSA is not the issue, as long as they are not liquids or aerosols. Your potential issue is with Customs and Immigration; if they are not allowed inside the US, it is illegal to bring them. They were _not allowed_ some years ago, I don't know the current status.

Comment: It is not the Kinder Happy Hippo that is prohibited, those are fine. It is the Kinder Surprise Egg, which contains a toy. US regulation doesn't allow a non-food object inside food where is cannot be seen.

Answer (score 8):

There shouldn't be any issue with TSA, as they are concerned with the normal airport security question of dangerous items. [TSA permits non-liquid chocolates and candy](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/candy).

The issue with Kinder products is around Kinder Eggs. These contain toys that do not meet US safety standards for children under 3, and so [are prohibited](https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/local-media-release/cross-border-travelers-are-reminded-kinder-egg-ban). You can read [the FDA Import Alert](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cms_ia/importalert_107.html) for "Confectionery Products Containing Non-Nutritive Components"; you'll see it lists Kinder Surprise and other chocolate eggs specifically.

As far as I can tell, Kinder Happy Hippos do not contain toys (or, in the language of the government, "Non-Nutritive Components"), so this shouldn't be an issue.

You'll be asked to complete [a customs declaration form](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/sample-declaration-form) when you enter the US, and one of those questions asks if you're bringing any kind of food. You may have some additional questions as a result, but my experience is that you'll usually be waved through pretty quickly if you just explain you have prepackaged candy.